# How to join two tables using LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

i am trying to join two tables  using the mvc4 web API and linq.

This is the class code for catagory table.

```
 public partial class catagory
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string cat_name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> measure_type { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> active { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> parent_cat { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> display_order { get; set; }
    public string cat_image { get; set; }
}
```

code of the class for product table

```
public partial class product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string p_name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> price { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> catagory_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> brand_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> active { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> discount_percent { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> display_order { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> color_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> seller_id { get; set; }
    public int selling_price { get; set; }
}
```

I want to join these two table. here is the code in the ProductController.cs file

```
 public class ProductController : ApiController
{

    public List<product> GetProductByColour(int id)
    {
        var query = (from x in db.products.AsEnumerable()
                     join y in db.catagories.AsEnumerable()
                     on x.id equals y.id
                     where x.id.Equals(id)
                     select new product
                     {
                         id = x.id,
                         p_name = x.p_name,
                         price = x.price,
                         catagory_id = y.id,
                         brand_id = x.brand_id,
                         display_order = y.display_order,

                     }).ToList();
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem are you facing ?

Comment: Actually when the code runs and I put a debugger on the return statement line, then it is showing as "Count=0".

Comment: I want to join the two tables. This is my query

Comment: LINQ has nothing to do with MVC or Web API. This is a question about EF and you *shouldn't* be using joins or calls to `AsEnumerable`. You should define a relation between the two classes so that Product has a `Category` property and Category has a `Products` collection. `AsEnumerable` on the other hand, loads everything in memory before applying any other filters. That's a *bad* idea as performance will suffer if you have more than a few dozen rows

Answer (score 1):

You should join both these table on products table catagory_id property  and category table Id property, because in your schema only this one looks valid relation

And incoming variale Id can be any of these like Product Id, Category Id or may be color_id. For me it seems more color_id.

For more information on linq please follow this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693042.aspx)

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
    {

        public List<product> GetProductByColour(int id)
        {
            var query = (from x in db.products.AsEnumerable()
                         join y in db.catagories.AsEnumerable()
                         on x.catagory_id equals y.id 
                         where x.id.Equals(id)
                         select new product
                         {
                             id = x.id,
                             p_name = x.p_name,
                             price = x.price,
                             catagory_id = y.id,
                             brand_id = x.brand_id,
                             display_order = y.display_order,

                         }).ToList();
            return query;
        }
```

Comment: EF and any ORM deals with relations. Using joins is a very bad idea even if it makes this query run *this time*. Simply by using enumerables, this query will crawl to a halt once a few dozen rows are added

Comment: Agreed..that's why i added link for linq MSDN article. Better approach will be to add relation between entities and then you can get those entities according to your need. I prefer to write this way when data is very high(more then 1000 rows), but i never do ienumerable. In place of that i prefer to do list after my customized object.

Comment: Thanks a  lot. i got the solution